# $.ajax() not posting on controller page

Tags: php, ajax, post, controller

I have this code written in one of the old project I got. According to this code the AJAX posts the data on the controller page and further functionality is carried out there. Here is the code:

```
 $("#esti").submit(function(e){
                $("#Complete").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                e.preventDefault();
                var formObj = $(this);
                var emborderID = '?emborder_id='+'<?php echo $emborder_id?>';
                var formURL = "order_process_controller.php"+emborderID;

                if(window.FormData !== undefined)  // for HTML5 browsers
                {
                    $(".loading").show();
                    var formData = new FormData(this);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: formURL,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data:  formData,
                        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        processData:false,
                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                        {
                               $(".loading").hide();
                            if(data=="success"){
                                window.location.href = "my_account.php";
                            }else if(data=="false"){
                                $("#msg_box").addClass("error-message");                            
                            }
                            else{
                                $("#msg_box").addClass("error-message");
                                $("#msg_box").html(data).show();
                            }

                            $("#Complete").removeAttr("disabled");
                            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#msg_box').offset().top }, 'fast');
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                        {
                            console.log(jqXHR);
                        }          
                   });

               }
               else  //for older browsers
                {
                    //generate a random id
                    var  iframeId = 'unique' + (new Date().getTime());

                    //create an empty iframe
                    var iframe = $('<iframe src="javascript:false;" name="'+iframeId+'" />');

                    //hide it
                    iframe.hide();

                    //set form target to iframe
                    formObj.attr('target',iframeId);

                    //Add iframe to body
                    iframe.appendTo('body');
                    iframe.load(function(e)
                    {
                        var doc = getDoc(iframe[0]);
                        var docRoot = doc.body ? doc.body : doc.documentElement;
                        var data = docRoot.innerHTML;
                        //data is returned from server.
                        if(data=="success"){
                            window.location.href = "my_account.php";
                        }else if(data=="false"){
                            $("#msg_box").addClass("error-message");                            
                        }                       
                        else{
                            $("#msg_box").addClass("error-message");
                            $("#msg_box").html(data).show();
                    }

                        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#msg_box').offset().top }, 'fast');
                    });

                }    
            });
    });
```

Now here I am facing an issue that sometimes the page does not initiate the AJAX request or something else happened and the page posted the data on the same page rather then posting it on to the controller page.

Please help.